# Powershell Runbook - The term 'Get-AzureRMWebAppSlot' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I'm trying to switch connection strings of a website to perform DB Failover, as part of HighAvailability. Please suggest if there are any suitable workarounds for the current requirement.

However, the same script which ran on my local machine is not executing while in the Azure portal as a PowerShell Workflow Runbook.

#### Powershell Code:

```
Set-AzureRMWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $reourceGroupName -Name $WebSiteName -ConnectionStrings $SecnodaryConnectionStrings -Slot $WebSiteSlot
```

#### Error:

```
    Set-AzureRMWebAppSlot : The term 'Set-AzureRMWebAppSlot' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.
    At AppService-DBConnnectionFailoverSwitch:37 char:37
    + 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-AzureRMWebAppSlot:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: please mark it as an answer, it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding modules to your automation account under Assets
Assets > Modules > Add a Module
Browse Gallery to find AzureRM.Compute

Comment: so whats the purpose of this question?

Comment: I could not find this anywhere, thought this could help some one

Comment: this is literally all over the place ;) this is not specific to this cmdlet